# Besteht der Text aus unverständlichem "Denglisch"?

Tags: english-to-german, sentence-structure

Zu dem hier gezeigtenText habe ich den unten gedruckten Kommentar erhalten. Ist er gerechtfertigt?

> > Die zweite Hälfte des in der Frage zu findenden Satzes könnte andeuten, dass der Frage stellender nicht "the", sondern "an" in der ersten Hälfte meint. Andererseits, wenn der Satz Teil einer Predigt ist, könnte der Satz eine vermeintliche Feststellung sein. Das gesagt, muss man in dem Fall annehmen, dass der Frage stellender das Zustandekommen des Buches durch beide Geschlechter glaubt. Nur in dem Sinne könnte das Buch "Gleichheit repräsentieren". Im letzteren Fall hätte er größere Gefahren zu befürchten als die, die der "Expertenführer" des "XX" auftreiben könnte!
>
> Du sprichst in Rätseln. Sorry, YYYY, dieses seltsame Denglisch kann niemand wirklich verstehen.

Comment: Schwer verständlich ist es schon, aber eine Mischung mit Englisch sehe ich nicht, bis auf _das gesagt_ vielleicht.

Comment: Wenn man unter »Denglisch« auch die Verwendung englischer Grammatik mit deutschen Wörtern versteht, dann ist der Text definitiv denglisch. Und diese Grammatikfehler sind auch die Ursache dafür, dass der Text schwer verständlich ist. Für mich sieht der Text aus, als hätte ihn eine Übersetzungssoftware (z.B. Google Translate) ausgespuckt.

Comment: Die Hinweise sind sehr hilfreich! Eine Übersetzungssoftware würde ich niemals verwenden! Zwecks Überprüfung gehe ich aber in der Tat zu "Duden Textprüfung" und erhalte von dort nicht viele Korrekturanmeldungen. Jetzt bin ich auf einmal etwas skeptisch "Duden" gegenüber geworden. Now back, therefore, to the drawing board!

Comment: Die aktuell vorhandene Antwort ist m.E. schon ziemlich gut. Wenn Du diesen Text (zumindest gedanklich, weil Deine Muttersprache vielleicht Englisch ist) aus dem Englischen übersetzt hast, könnte es helfen, das englische "Original" zu ergänzen. Wörter wie _Predigt_, _Geschlechter_ und _Expertenführer_ sehen hier erst mal harmlos und plausibel aus, könnten aber u.U. doch _false friends_ sein.

Answer (score 5):

Ich finde 3 Stellen, die salopp als Denglisch bezeichnet werden könnten, zwei davon sind darüber hinaus schlicht falsch:

> dass der Frage stellender nicht "the", sondern "an" in der ersten Hälfte meint.
>
> dass der Frage stellender das Zustandekommen des Buches

Es gibt im Deutschen den Fragesteller, der hier zu der Fragesteller bzw. der Fragestellende werden müsste. Klein- und Auseinanderschreibung sind im Englischen, aber nicht nur dort, zuhause. Hier ist aber auch die Endung misslungen.

> Das gesagt, muss man in dem Fall annehmen, dass ...

"Das gesagt ..." ist keine stehende Redewendung und klingt sehr nach "Having said that ...", ist aber nicht falsch.

Ebenfalls fehlerhaft ist das teilkorrigierte:

> Das gesagt, muss man in dem Fall annehmen, dass der Fragestellende das Zustandekommen des Buches durch beide Geschlechter glaubt.

Ohne mehr Kontext würde ich nur wagen zu raten, dass hier ein *an* fehlt, *an das Zustandekommen des Buches ... glaubt*. Man könnte aber auch *glaubt* durch *erwartet* ersetzen, ohne ein *an* einzufügen. Einen Anglizismus erkenne ich darin nicht, aber dem Verständnis abträglich ist es natürlich schon.

Comment: Für die Hinweise bin ich sehr dankbar! Recht zu jedem Preis haben ist natürlich nicht mein Ziel, aber ist der genannte Kommentar "kann niemand wirklich verstehen" zutreffend?

Comment: @CliftonRoad: Es ist eine Frage der Geduld. Wenn das der erste Absatz eines langen Textes ist, dann ist ein Aufgeben verständlich. Mit etwas gutem Willen und Geduld lässt sich aber erkennen, was gemeint sein könnte. Bei einem mehrseitigen Text müsste ich mir aber viel vom Inhalt versprechen, um mir sowas anzutun.